# How to consume Facebook's "autocomplete anything" suggest-style dropdown

Tags: ajax, web-services, facebook, autocomplete, autosuggest

When you go to edit your favorite music or movies on Facebook, you will notice an autocomplete suggest list that is basically a list of "everything" (brand names, music artists, movies, etc.)  How can someone consume that list in their own code?  Is it part of the Facebook API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They wrap some of the functionality in their FBML fields, but their developer wiki shows [how they do what they do](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FBJS/Examples/Typeahead).  If you want to consume their data though, you're going to have to [play with an HTTP proxy](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and figure out what parameters to send to their server.  There are also a couple parameters that seem to be session based, so I don't know how well you're going to be able to integrate this into your own application.

Answer (score 0):

This was working for awhile, but now they require the session cookie, so we'll have to hope they add support for this to the graph api, unless you want to fight w/ the proxy.